# Xamarin/WPF bind to changes

Tags: xamarin, animation, data-binding

Im creating a card game, I have CardModel, and DeckModel. Standard stuff. I do a summary here with simplified code.

```
public class CardModel : INotifyPropertyChaned
{
    // all memebers with get, set implementing with NotifyPropertyChanged()
    public int Strength;
    public Color BackSide;
    //etc 
}

public class DeckModel : INotifyPropertyChaned {
    // all memebers with get, set implementing with NotifyPropertyChanged()
    public ObservableCollection<CardModel> Cards;
    public void InsertFront(CardModel c);
    public void InsertBack(CardModel c);
    public CardModel TakeFromTop();
    public void Shuffle();
}
```

The game has different piles of cards (Decks) and cards are taken from one of them and unserted in the other. The Hand of the player, for instance, is also a Deck of cards. We just use different UI components to show it different on screen.

The backend has been coded by another person and he does all the logic as you expect, like for example:

```
 public void UserRequestNewCard()
 {
    CardModel c = MainDeck.TakeFromTop();
    PlayerHand.InsertFront(c);
 }
```

Now I need to do the UI. I created controls called CardViewer and DeckViewer and Bind to properties, like the Cards.Count for the deck. And everything works like a charm. I see the numbers going up and down when cards are taken or added. Stuff like:

```
<ContentView xmlns:blablabla
             x:Class="MyGame.DeckViewer"/>
  <Frame blablba
      <Label Text="{Binding Cards.Count}"/>
  />
/>

public partial class DeckViewer : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public Deck Cards {get; set;}
   public DeckViewer() => InitializeComponent();
   public Bind(DeckModel deck)
   {
      this.Bindingcontest= deck; 
   }
}
```

but ..

How can I detect from the UI that a card is being transferred from one Deck to another Deck so I can do an animation showing a card, or a box, moving from A to B before actually changing the content of the component ??

Comment: your model should probably raise an event to indicate that a card is being moved

Comment: this is non-elegant approach, but this lead to weird behaviours where the destination deck get's updated before the animated card arrives to the deck and looks weird.

Comment: I'm not sure what's not "elegant" about it.  If you want your other UI updates to be dependent on the card animation, then you need to solve for that problem.  Data Binding might not be the right solution if you want more granular control of UI updates.

Comment: if you see you hand of cards on screen. Then you click the button for a new card. The backend does get a card from the deck, and adds it to you hand.  But what you on screen is a card poping into your hand out of the nowhere, and at the same time an animation of a card moving from the deck to the already existing card in your hand. Far from elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason suggested, when you are involved in the operation from one Deck to another Deck, you can encapsulate the animation of the movement of a card in advance, and then call this animation method every time when there is a card movement in the method. This will looks more elegant.

For how to use it, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/